# Send an AJAX response and rebuild a form in a single AJAX callback

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I need to execute multiple AJAXCommands and rebuild form in one AJAXCallback function, but the documentation says the AJAXCallback function should return AjaxResponse OR FormElement.

Using ReplaceCommand to replace an element is difficult because after the AjaxCallback SubmitButton should be searched, and its #Submit function.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here's a tutorial I wrote on doing ajax in the Form API correctly: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-form-api-ajax-form-and-results-same-page